# error while tring to create new entry on jpa table

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

Im using the following code the insert data to JPA and Im getting error when im trying to do the commit ,the object is with the full data so i dont understand what am I missing here,any idea?

```
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(object);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

the entity look like this with all the getters and setters

```
@Entity
public class LeaveRequest {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private int id;
private String type;
private String from;
private String to;
private String length;
private String state;

public int getId() {

    return id;
}
```

**the error is:**

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "FROM" at line 1, column 31.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO LEAVEREQUEST (ID, FROM, LENGTH, STATE, TO, TYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [6 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(LeaveRequest [id=1, type=VACATION, from=2012-12-27, to=2012-12-27, length=1 day, state=Rejected])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FROM` is a sql reserved keyword.

Just change the variable name or use the @Column annotation to change the column name of the table column.

Comment: Many databases will allow you to use a reserved word as an identifier if you delimit the identifier (e.g. `"FROM"`). You might be able to do this via a `@Column` annotation (`@Column(name="\"FROM\"")`).

Comment: @BrianVosburgh That I have no idea about, but then again is it worth it? Personally I feel this approach will mess with the Query readability....

Answer (score 0):

wow, cool. you have an attribute called "from" and it clashes with SQL reserved word.
 I would say it's a bug in your jpa provider, but who knows, maybe such behaviour is jpa compliant. as a workaround you can rename the column in the database and add a @column annotation to from attribute, with name="newcolumnname"